# A doubt on a calculus problem involving finding the highest point of a function

Tags: calculus

In Simmons's Calculus with Analytic Geometric, 2nd edition, p.129, a problem asks to find the highest point on the loop described by the function 
$x^3+y^3=3xy$, whose graph looks like this:

[image]

Since the loop is in the first quadrant, I think one way to find the answer is to take the derivative of the function, set it equal to zero and pick the resulting $x>0$, right? So I differentiated the function and obtained $\dfrac{y-x^2}{y^2-x}=0 \implies y=x^2$.

However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Since I had to use implicit differentation to arrive at the derivative I imagine I would now have to solve the original equation for $y$ and then substitute it for $y$ in $y=x^2$ (at least that's how I've approached similar problems), but I'm finding it especially difficult to solve for $y$. I wonder if there's an easier way to tackle this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to solve the original equation for $y$. You deduced that $y = x^2$ whenver the slope of the curve is flat. There's no reason you can't substitute $y = x^2$ into the original equation *as is* and solve that equation for $x$. You can then compute the corresponding $y$ value by using $y = x^2$ (after all, regardless of what the *general* formula for $y$ is, we know that *at the particular points we're interested in*, $y = x^2$).

If we substitute $x^2$ in for $y$ in the original equation, we obtain
\begin{align*}
x^3 + x^6 &= 3x^3 \\
\implies x^6 - 2x^3 &= 0 \\
\implies x^3(x^3 - 2) &= 0
\end{align*}
which gives us the two solutions $x = 0$ or $\sqrt[3]{2}$. The second one is obviously the one we want, and we can obtain the corresponding $y$ value (i.e. the highest point of the curve in the first quadrant) by computing
\begin{align*}
y &= x^2 \\
&= (\sqrt[3]{2})^2 \\
&= 2^{2/3}
\end{align*}